# Input multiple images in a shape of an array

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from PIL import Image

train_path_positive = "/content/Dataset_P5/Train/Positive"

positive_patches = []
for filename in os.listdir(train_path_positive):
  image = cv2.imread(train_path_positive + "/" +filename,0)
  image = cv2.resize(image, (500,500))
  print(image.shape)
  positive_patches.append(image)

positive_patches_array = np.array(positive_patches)
```

I have 15 pictures in jpg format

When i try to print the shape, I got `(15,)` and
I was trying to input those picture and store it on array with the format `(15, 500,500)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preallocate a numpy array

```
# Use your required dtype in below line
positive_patches_array = np.empty((15,500,500), dtype='uint16')


for num, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(train_path_positive)): 
    image = cv2.imread(train_path_positive + "/" +filename,0)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (500,500))   
    positive_patches_array[num, :, :] = image
```